# find a row # of the selected item in listbox vba

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

How can i find the row # of selected item in listbox?

right now i have a `sub` that inputs all of the found item into the listbox, see below

```
Sub findnext()
Dim Name As String
Dim f As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim s As Integer
Dim findnext As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
Name = surname.Value
ListBox1.Clear
Set f = Range("A:A").Find(what:=Name, LookIn:=xlValues)
Set findnext = f

Do
 Debug.Print findnext.Address
 Set findnext = Range("A:A").findnext(findnext)

 ListBox1.AddItem findnext.Value
 ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = ws.Cells(findnext.Row, xFirstName).Value
 ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = ws.Cells(findnext.Row, xTitle).Value
 ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 3) = ws.Cells(findnext.Row, xProgramAreas).Value
 ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 4) = ws.Cells(findnext.Row, xEmail).Value
 ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 5) = ws.Cells(findnext.Row, xStakeholder).Value
 ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 6) = ws.Cells(findnext.Row, xofficephone).Value
 ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 7) = ws.Cells(findnext.Row, xcellphone).Value
'ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 8) = ws.Cells(findnext.Row, xFirstName).Value
Loop While findnext.Address <> f.Address

End Sub
```

and if the user selects the item in the listbox, then it'll populate the information into the textbox of the userform

```
Sub ListBox1_Click()

    surname.Value = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 0)
    firstname.Value = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 1)
    tod.Value = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 2)
    program.Value = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 3)
    email.Value = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 4)
    SetCheckBoxes ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 5)        '<<<< added
    officenumber.Value = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 6)
    cellnumber.Value = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 7)     

End Sub
```

i want to figure out from `ListBox1_click()` how i can determine the row # of the selected item in the listbox. once i figure this out, i'll code an `update sub` where it'll locate the row # of the selected item and i'll re-enter the information in the textboxes and update the information of the row.

i thought about storing a row # in a hidden worksheet when i do `find`.. but i don't know how to link the row # of the `found` with what's been selected in the `listbox`

hopefully...this makes sense, if not please let me know!

Answer (score 3):

I've found a way to go around this - i've made an extra listcolumn to store the `row#` of the `found` when the item's been searched. then i made another textbox within the userform that would input the row#:

therefore, within the `findnext()` sub i added the following line `storerownumber = findnext.row` and added another line for listbox. `listbox1.list(listbox1.listcount-1,8) = storerownumber

and within the `listbox1_click()` sub i've added the following line: `rownumber.value = listbox1.list(listbox1.listindex,8)`

and made a new `sub update_click()` and added the following lines:

```
Dim r As Long
Dim update As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Master")
rownumber.Value = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 8)
r = rownumber

ws.Cells(r, xLastName).Value = surname.Value
ws.Cells(r, xFirstName).Value = firstname.Value
ws.Cells(r, xTitle).Value = tod.Value
ws.Cells(r, xProgramAreas).Value = program.Value
ws.Cells(r, xEmail).Value = email.Value
ws.Cells(r, xStakeholder).Value = GetCheckBoxes
ws.Cells(r, xofficephone).Value = officenumber.Value
ws.Cells(r, xcellphone).Value = cellnumber.Value

end sub
```

and it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you have to loop through all rows in **ListBox** since you can have Multi-Select.

```
For r = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(r) Then
        Debug.Print "You selected row #" & r + 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: so i used the following code you've provided, except instead of using `debug.print` i wrote the following: `worksheets("hs").cells(1,1) = r` and it gave me a value of 1 in `hs`. `hs` is the hidden sheet where i want to store the row# of selected item. problem is, it's giving me the row# from the listbox, not a row# that it found from (from the excel spreadsheet). eg., if i have an entry named `apple` and i do a `search` and i find apple, it input all info about apple into `listbox`. my question is how do i find the row# of `apple` when it was selected from `listbox`? does that make sense...?

Comment: I thought you asked "how i can determine the row # of the selected item in the listbox"? Are you trying to save/find the worksheet cells that is contained in the ListBox when you click on of them?

Comment: Ya, i'm trying to find the row# of the item that's in the worksheets once i click it from the listbox. the listbox gets populated after `find` function, so i want to find the row# of the `found` item once it's been clicked in the listbox

Comment: I suggest you to modify your **find** function and put something like `WorksheetName!A1` into last column of the list box (not necessary to be shown to user), then upon clicking, activate that Worksheet and select that Range.